# An svg images turn upside-down after adding to assets Swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, svg, assets

So, I have an image, when I open it - it looks fine

But when I add it to the project it becomes upside down
I've tried adding to the project an upside-down picture (so it rotates again and becomes normal) or rotated 90 degrees but in project it is somehow always pointed down

UPD: It works fine in an app, only displaying wrong in the xcode

[clipboard SVG initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Tb0.png)

[same picture in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIetE.png)

[90 degrees rotated image added to proj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCFcm.png)

Comment: Can you add a link to your project?

Comment: @enxaneta yep 
https://github.com/flowereDnap/-

Comment: Also, it works fine in app and goes wrong only in Xcode assets preview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score -2):

you can delete assets folder and create new one then try again maybe problem is assests folder.

Comment: Nuh, I've created a whole new project to demonstrate it, but the problem is still there
I think its something with SVG pictures, but they display normal in an app hence nothing to worry about, just curious wtf

Comment: yeah i guess its probably you svg file have problem you can use if it is possible png format maybe you can fix it issue btw can you up vote my answer i need to get 3 points for comments. lol